# Can I connect website "A" through LAN and website "B" through WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, intranet

I am connecting LAN and WiFi simultaneously. But I want to connect company's intranet through LAN with proxy and public websites through WiFi directly without proxy. Can I set this to work automatically?

Example:

Type "www.google.com" in the address bar, automatically use LAN to connect

Type "www.yahoo.com" in the address bar, automatically use WiFi to connect

How can I set this to work? I am connecting LAN and Wifi already.

Comment: In general, you can have a default route for anything unspecified, and then define a set of static routes for exceptions. I know of no "simple" way of having this happen automatically. With VPNs, the default route is automatically changed. But if you're talking about having routes change automatically, based on the status of your WiFi connection, you'd have to make use of third party software—or write some kind of script yourself. And any specific answer to this would rely on a lot more information than you've provided.

Comment: Do you know what kind of script can I use? Sorry that I do not know what information is needed to better clarify the situation. To simplify the issue, say for example, when I type www.google.com in the address bar, it will use LAN to connect, when I type www.yahoo.com, it will use the WiFi to connect. Would it be simplier to tackle?

Comment: Ah. So, if you're talking about using *specific* websites on one interface, and others on a different one (not internal sites on one interface and everything external on another) it becomes trickier. If there is a specific site you always want to reach on one *and* it's IP address never changes, you can add a static route for it or its range of subnets (If it has one). But if it's less specific than that, I'm afraid something like what you want isn't going to be feasible.